# RegularExpression validator asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex

It's been a long day and I have one little bit left to do on my coursework, but I cant see for the life of me why this regular expression validator isnt working in my aspx file.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>    
    <br />
    Product:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="a-z only" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-z]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 


    <br />
    <br />
```

```
    <br />
    Old Name:     

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddItems" runat="server" Width="128px" AutoPostBack="true" >                         
    </asp:DropDownList> 

    <br />
    <br />
    New Name: 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox3_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="a-z only" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-z]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 


    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Update Name" />


    <div align="left">
<asp:Button ID="back" runat="server" Text="Back" onclick="back_Click" />
```

Sometimes they allow text, which is the desired behavoir, sometimes they don't. Could this be down to my c sharp code or is the bug definitely in the aspx file?

regards, Lewis.

Comment: Maybe I'm tired too, but what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I only want a-z to be allowed.

Comment: It looks like your regex is case sensitive, is that what you intended? Or did you want [A-Za-z] ?

Comment: @LewisElliott: Are you sure? Do you want to disallow upper case letters? Letters with accents? Spaces? Because `a-z` disallows all these things.

Comment: Ah I see, didnt realise it was case sensitive. I want to allow spaces and capitals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, change your regex to `"^[A-Za-z ]*$"` if you want to allow lower and upper case letters as well as white space in any order. Note that this regex will also match empty string as there are no required number of characters.